# ReactJS: Cannot find module './App.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I opened my old project today and saw these strange warnings:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx:13:17
TS2307: Cannot find module './App.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
    11 | import { Layout, Breadcrumb } from 'antd'
    12 | import Header from './components/Header/Header'
  > 13 | import css from './App.module.css'
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    14 | import { ROUTES } from './constants/routes'
    15 | import Menu from './components/Menu'
    16 |

ERROR in src/components/common/FormsControls/FormsControls.tsx:2:17
TS2307: Cannot find module './FormsControls.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.
    1 | import { FC, MouseEvent } from 'react'
  > 2 | import css from './FormsControls.module.css'
      |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import commonCss from '../styles.module.css'
    4 | import { Field, WrappedFieldProps } from 'redux-form'
    5 | import cn from 'classnames'
```

There are also a lot of them with file formats svg, png and others. All my packages are now the most recent version.
There was no such problem before, can anyone help solve this without having to struggle with webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `declarations.d.ts` (you can name it anything you want) 
Sometimes it is mandatory to reload your IDE but not always.

```
// declarations.d.ts
declare module '*.css';
declare module '*.scss';
declare module '*.svg';
// etc ...
```

TypeScript does not know that there are files other than .ts or .tsx hence it will complain if an import has an unknown file suffix, so in this case, we explicitly tell the compiler that we mean to load a module that can have the following extensions.

Comment: I put this file in the project and restart folder but I still see errors in the console

Comment: May I see the structure of your folders, please?

Answer (score 0):

In my React app, created with CRA, I had to add in **react-app-env.d.ts**:

```
declare module '*.css';
```

**Adding this declaration in separate file, like suggested above, did not work.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).